# TYPO3: tx_news: separate pagination between plugins

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm using TYPO3 7.6 with the latest tx_news release from TER.

I want to show two news plugins at one page: one is configured to show all news from storage folder "A"; the other one is configured to show only the latest record from storage folder "B".

Now, once the first plugin paginates, the second one renders empty content since it tries to paginate as well (which doesn't make sense since it should display only the latest record).

So, my question is: How can I separate the pagination between both plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked the fluid template to totally avoid the pagination in this case (based on "settings.templateLayout"

Answer (score 3):

In TYPO3 7.6 there is no solution to your issue, sorry. Workarounds include adding manual pagination for the second plugin or overriding the second widget with one that forces a different ID.

In TYPO3 8.6+ you can override the ID of each widget which causes the URL scope to change so you can isolate parameters for each widget. More information can be found on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Feature-47006-ExtendTheWidgetIdentifierWithCustomString.html

Comment: The link has changed: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-47006-ExtendTheWidgetIdentifierWithCustomString.html

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime (I don't know whether it was in place three years ago) there is an option `Hide the pagination` in the news plugin. You will find it in the tab `Additional`.

So if you place more than one list view on one page, you can disable pagination for all lists, which should not get paginated.